# Best way to export huge data from Oracle DB to Oracle DB

Tags: sql, database, oracle, csv

That's my first post in stackoverflow, and i've to say that i really like that website !

For a project i need to export then re-import some huge Oracle tables from one DB to another (around 100 million lines and 30 rows).

My idea is to export the table in a flat file and then reimport into another empty table considering that the schema already exists.

I'm using PL/SQL Developer and/or SQL*Plus to make my operations.

I've tested SQL*Loader which seems to do a good job but it's really slow in my opinion : about 30 seconds to make an import of a CSV file with 1 million lines/30 rows.

Which solution could you bring? Is SQL*Loader is the best tool? Some better tools already exists?
Is CSV the better format talking about size and processing time?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Do you have to do this once or routinely?

Comment: After i've found the good tool, i've got to make a java program that will make the operation on demand, so it's not really routinely (it's like 4 times a year...)

Comment: Why are you writing your own tool, rather than using data pump?

Comment: I've never heard of data pump... What is it? How does it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Oracle DataPump aka expdp and impdp [Overview of Oracle Data Pump](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_overview.htm) See [Examples of Using Data Pump Export](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_export.htm#SUTIL882) and [Examples of Using Data Pump Import](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_import.htm#SUTIL954)

There really is no need to program this on your own, there is no way that you can outperform expdp/impdp. Don't forget there is also an impdp option to use a network_link. In that case, you just skip the dmp file and import directly into the target database. This can be done using impdp from the commandline but also using dbms_datapump using pl/sql. See [PL/SQL Packages and Types Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e16760/d_datpmp.htm) for docu.

Comment: It seems to be a good solution but my DBA don't want to give my the right to create directory...

Comment: in that case ask him to create that directory for you, of ask him to give you a procedure to do that for you. In that way, the dba is in control.

Comment: The thing is we are actually on the development server, and even if we have the right now, we won't have it in production...

Comment: If the business requirements are strong, they could/should give you a procedure to do the job, keeping the dba's in control. they don't want you to be able to create ANY directory on the server.

Comment: Hum i don't know... But people at work told me to do without it...
I've just found this copy SQLPLUS command which seems to work well, what do you think about it ? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a90842/apb.htm

Comment: In that case I would go for impdp using a db link, for consistency.

Comment: @ik_zelf Hi, can this way use from Oracle DB to PostgreSQL? Thank you so much!

Comment: @Begin2Pip no. The file formats are not documented. Easiest for Oracle -> postgres data migration is -my opinion- to use foreign data wrapper from postgres and pull the data in. There are a few tiny differences regarding handling of NULL and empty strings ....

Comment: @ik_zelf Thank you so much for your prompt reply, I am exporting  both.csv and .sql formats to the local, then I can know well the structure of database, and import data in postgres with .sql files, I know it's stupid, could you please tell me more details about `foreign data wrapper`? Do you know some tutorials or documents? Really appreciate! I am a newbie Python developer in web, database is really hard for me! 

Comment: @Begin2Pip Here is a nice article about foreign data wrappers and oracle. Let the database do the work. That is smarter than working with files ....

Answer (score 2):

You can use one of the following option:

1. SQL Loader (which you already might be trying out).
2. Traditional data export and Import (exp / imp commands).
3. Oracle data pump (expdp /impdp).

Also if you need to do this regularly then you can schedule this using oracle scheduler or shell script.